# How to clear the consul in jmeter - using groovy

Tags: groovy, jmeter

I have a question about the printing that I perform in Jmeter, I use 
System.out.println and the consul is full with data.
the problem is that if I want in each iteration to clear the consul how can I do it?
the consul is full with data from last run, or Prev thread and I just want to clear it.
regards (it is the black consul that opened in a new window.)[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should log messages using `log.info("Hello World");` (*log* is a script global variable) instead of using `OUT` in your scripts. Therefore, the logs will be sent to `jmeter.log` file.

See the documentation about [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows you can use something like:

```
new ProcessBuilder('cmd', '/c', 'cls').inheritIO().start().waitFor()
```

For other operating system it will depend on [SHELL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell) implementation, you will need to amend the command line according to your requirements, most likely using [`clear`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/clear) command.

References:

- [ProcessBuilder documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)
- [Groovy is the New Black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)